# Hashing program not returning identical values for the same file

Tags: c, loops, hash, openssl

This hashing function I've created (that scans for new files, and computes their hashes) seemingly functions, however once removing a file, for example test.c, and then replacing it with the exact same file it returns 2 different hash values. By this I mean that whilst the program is running the first calculation might return a hash of 1234, for example, and once deleting and placing the same file within the folder the it then returns 2345.

There seems to be no order, as 1234 could be the result 5 times in a row. I wondered whether there's any strikingly obvious reason in this code?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/inotify.h>
#include <openssl/sha.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
        int fd;
        unsigned char c[SHA512_DIGEST_LENGTH];
        int i;
        SHA512_CTX mdContext;
        int bytes;
        unsigned char data[1024];
        const int event_size = sizeof(struct inotify_event);
        const int buf_len = 1024 * (event_size + FILENAME_MAX);
        char *directory = "/home/joe/Documents/";
        char *hashDirectory = "/home/joe/Documents/_Hash/";
        char hashInBuf[100];
        char hashOutBuf[100];
        fd = inotify_init();

        if (fd < 0) {
          perror("inotify_init");
        }
        while (1) {
          char buff[buf_len];
          int no_of_events, count = 0;

          //SEARCH FOR NEW FILES WITHIN DIRECTORY
          no_of_events = read (fd, buff, buf_len);
          while (count < no_of_events) {
            struct inotify_event *event = (struct inotify_event *)&buff[count];
            if (event->len) {
              if ((event->mask & IN_CREATE))
              if(!(event->mask & IN_ISDIR)) {
                printf("\n%s has been created\n", event->name);

                //CONJOIN DIRECTORY AND FILENAME / EXTENSION
                snprintf(hashInBuf, sizeof(hashInBuf), "%s/%s", directory, event->name);
                snprintf(hashOutBuf, sizeof(hashOutBuf), "%s/%s.txt", hashDirectory, event->name);

                FILE *ftest=fopen(hashInBuf, "rb");
                FILE *ftest2=fopen(hashOutBuf, "wt");

                //HASH FUNCTION
                SHA512_Init (&mdContext);
                while ((bytes = fread (data, 1, 1024, ftest)) != 0)
                SHA512_Update (&mdContext, data, bytes);
                SHA512_Final (c,&mdContext);
                for(i = 0; i < SHA512_DIGEST_LENGTH; i++){
                  fprintf(ftest2, "%02x", c[i]);
                  printf("%02x", c[i]);
                }
                fclose (ftest);
                fclose (ftest2);
                fflush (stdout);
              }
            }
            count += event_size + event->len;
          }
        }
        return 0;
}
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: can you try using `md5sum <filename>` for both files ? If that's also different, then the files aren't *actually* the same.

Comment: @SanderDeDycker I'm attempting to check the same file so it only results in one hash from using the method you asked. I'm deleting the one that is in the scanned folder, and then placing the same file back into said folder (to verify it works, which unfortunately as described it does not). The odd thing is there are only 2 outcomes of the function (i.e. the hash will either be A. or B. randomly).

Comment: Is one of the hashes by chance `cf83e1357eefb8bdf1542850d66d8007d620e4050b5715dc83f4a921d36ce9ce47d0d13c5d85f2b0ff8318d2877eec2f63b931bd47417a81a538327af927da3e`?

Comment: @Ctx Yes! Blimey I've been searching for a solution to this for a while haha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this line

```
if ((event->mask & IN_CREATE))
```

you wait for the event that a file is *created*. Then, your hashing function immediately starts running!
This may lead to the situation that the file is *not* fully written yet, so you only hashed a *part* of the file.

You should use the event `IN_CLOSE_WRITE` to make sure, that the file has already been completely written.

Another option is to *not* create the files in this directory, but creating them in a temporary directory and subsequently *moving* them into the target directory. The corresponding event is `IN_MOVED_TO` then.

Comment: Ah brilliant! Thank you so much, I'll have a crack at trying to implement that.

Comment: @JosephSmith yw ;)

Comment: sorry to bother again but where exactly should I place the `IN_CLOSE_WRITE`? I'm not very familiar (or good..) at coding ...!

Comment: instead of IN_CREATE